# Admob Ads doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

i was trying to set admob ads in my app with the new google-service-libs. and everything looks fine in genymotion emulator ads are showing up. but they don't at real device like my galaxy ace gt5830i with android 2.3.6. and i dont know what is the problem.

here is some code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImg"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="2dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_clicked"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/pager" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" >
    </View>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
        android:divider="#351802"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my Ad_Unit_Id is saved in string.xml file in res/ folder.

java :

```
AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest req = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        ad.loadAd(req);
```

Please tell me if you need more code. Thanks

Comment: Check the resolution of the banners and also the padding on the AdView.I guess the AdView size is 320 x 50 dip .. Also, check your logcat

Comment: Ok i will check and i will answer back thank you.

Comment: Post your logcat, it will tell you why you are not getting ads. It could be as simple as no ads being available for your device.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem before, it's because the ads banner needs a resolution that's bigger than the mobile's resolution.

For this reason test the application horizontally and once you do you'll be able to see the ads in full.

Comment: Ok i will try it horizontally. and i will answer back. thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the ad's `adsize` dynamically based on the devices' screen resolutions:

```
 AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;  

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();  
    double density = dm.density * 160;
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);   
    if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
        adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
    } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
        adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
    } else { // > 320 X 50
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
    }

    ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
     adView.setAdSize(adSize);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```